# Couldn't load XPCOM

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, firefox

When I try to open the Tor browser, I get a Firefox message box, saying: Couldn't load XPCOM . And no, I don't have any Webroot product. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Which Windows version do you use? Do you use some other form of anti-virus software?

Comment: Hi, I currently have a version of Kaspersky Free, but I have had Kaspersky for several months and I have never had problems opening the Tor browser, so I do not think it is a problem related to Kaspersky, although anything is possible, this has been happening to me for a few weeks. It is really desperate. My Windows version is: Windows 10 (Version 22H2) Thanks in advance.

Comment: KAspersky is a spyware that forcibly breaks SSL e.t.c. - remove it ASAP! There's a free Bit Defender that has this option switchable, so you turn it off and it's ok

Comment: How I said, Kaspersky had nothing to do with it. I uninstalled it and I stil cannot open Tor Browser. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Could you check if the recent release 12.5.6 fixes the problem for you?